# Java doesn't filter invalid characters when serializing xml documents

Tags: java, xml

I'm serializing an xml document in java 17.
I store this document in a file assuming I'll be able to deserialize it later.
Unfortunately, once I try to read it, I get a SAXParseException.
One of the characters is not a [valid character in XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML).
I would expect a document serialised by java to be deserializable by java.

I'm left with two questions:

1. How do I read the previously generated files which contain invalid characters?
2. How do I prevent newly generated files from containing invalid characters?

Minimum reproducible example:

```
package example;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // u001b = escape and is not allowed in xml 1.0
        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element element = document.createElement("tag");
        element.setAttribute("attribute", "\u001b");
        document.appendChild(element);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        System.out.println("transformerFactory.getClass() = " + transformerFactory.getClass());
        // transformerFactory.getClass() = class org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, US_ASCII.name());
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(bos));
        String xmlString = bos.toString(US_ASCII);

        System.out.println("xmlString = " + xmlString);
        // xmlString = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?><tag attribute="&#27;"/>

        DocumentBuilder domDocumentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        domDocumentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes(US_ASCII)));
        // [Fatal Error] :1:63: Character reference "&#27" is an invalid XML character.
        //     Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 63; Character reference "&#27" is an invalid XML character.
        //     at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:262)
        // at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:342)
        // at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:122)
        // at be.mips.cyberlab.business.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:40)
    }
}
```

Micheal Key suggests "use an API that checks the content, or you check it yourself before passing to the API", so I'm going to try that. It works, but I don't like walking the entire tree just to serialize it.

```
package example;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;
import static org.w3c.dom.Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE;
import static org.w3c.dom.Node.COMMENT_NODE;
import static org.w3c.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE;
import static org.w3c.dom.Node.TEXT_NODE;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

class Scratch {

    private static final Pattern VALID_CHARACTERS = Pattern.compile(
            "[\\u0009\\u000a\\u000d\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD]+");
    private static final Pattern INVALID_XML_CHARACTERS = Pattern.compile(
            "(?<![\\uD800-\\uDBFF])[\\uDC00-\\uDFFF]|[\\uD800-\\uDBFF](?![\\uDC00-\\uDFFF])|[\\x00-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x7F-\\x9F\\uFEFF\\uFFFE\\uFFFF]");
    private static final String REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER = "\uFFFD";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // u001b = escape and is not allowed in xml 1.0
        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element element = document.createElement("tag");
        element.setAttribute("attribute", "\u001b");
        document.appendChild(element);

        stripInvalidXmlCharacters(document);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        System.out.println("transformerFactory.getClass() = " + transformerFactory.getClass());
        // transformerFactory.getClass() = class org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
        final Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, US_ASCII.name());
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(bos));
        String xmlString = bos.toString(US_ASCII);

        System.out.println("xmlString = " + xmlString);
        // xmlString = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?><tag attribute="&#65533;"/>

        DocumentBuilder domDocumentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        domDocumentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes(US_ASCII)));
    }

    private static void stripInvalidXmlCharacters(Node node) {
        NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
        if (attributes != null) {
            int length = attributes.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Node attribute = attributes.item(i);
                attribute.setNodeValue(stripInvalidXmlCharacters(attribute.getNodeValue()));
            }
        }
        for (Node child = node.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
            switch (child.getNodeType()) {
                case ELEMENT_NODE -> stripInvalidXmlCharacters(child);
                case TEXT_NODE, CDATA_SECTION_NODE, COMMENT_NODE ->
                        child.setNodeValue(stripInvalidXmlCharacters(child.getNodeValue()));
            }
        }
    }

    private static String stripInvalidXmlCharacters(String input) {
        if (input == null || input.isEmpty() || VALID_CHARACTERS.matcher(input).matches()) {
            return input;
        }
        Matcher m = INVALID_XML_CHARACTERS.matcher(input);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER);
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: And you're surprised when you set the value of an attribute as a control character (the escape character)? Why are you doing that?

Comment: I can see how you'd think this is wierd in this contrived example where I create a document with some hardcoded data. The real documents are created with input from users and other systems. I'm suprised java would serialize a document without throwing an exception knowing that it will never be able to deserialize it later. If the solution is "strip control characters" from your input then it is a hassle, but I'll deal with it. But what do I do with previously created documents?

Comment: *But what do I do with previously created documents?* You'll have to 'clean' them. Xml files are *text* files and are not intended to contain binary data. When they do, they are usually in CDATA sections and even then Base64 encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I read the previously generated files which contain invalid characters?

You have to repair them using some non-XML-aware process. You can't use XML tools to read them.

> How do I prevent newly generated files from containing invalid characters?

You either use an API that checks the content, or you check it yourself before passing to the API.

The Xalan serializer, which is what you're using, was designed as the back end for an XSLT transformer, and it's very likely to be assuming that the XSLT processor is handing it valid content. The Saxon serializer, which is the same architecturally, makes the same assumption.